# Multiple event calendar crud using codeigniter, jquery and ajax

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to make a multiple event calendar crud using **CodeIgniter**. I am successful in making a single event calendar. I need help with the following:

```
class Calendar_model extends CI_Model {

var $conf;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

  $this->conf = array(
  'day_type' => 'long',
  'month_type' => 'short',
  'show_next_prev' => true,
  'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'Calendar/index'
);

$this->conf['template'] = '
  {table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">{/table_open}

  {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

  {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
  {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
  {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

  {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

  {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
  {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
  {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

  {cal_row_start}<tr class="days">{/cal_row_start}
  {cal_cell_start}<td class="day" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{/cal_cell_start}

  {cal_cell_content}
    <div class="day_num">{day}</div>
    <div class="content">{content}</div>
  {/cal_cell_content}
  {cal_cell_content_today}
    <div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>
    <div class="content">{content}</div>
  {/cal_cell_content_today}

  {cal_cell_no_content}<div class="day_num">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content}
  {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

  {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

  {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
  {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

  {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
';

}

function get_calendar_data($year, $month) { 
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT
(date, '%Y-%m-%e') AS date FROM 
tbl_calendar WHERE date LIKE '$year-$month%' "); //date format eliminates zeros make
          //days look 05 to 5

            $cal_data = array();

            foreach ($query->result() as $row) { //for every date fetch data
                $a = array();
                $i = 0;
                $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT data FROM tbl_calendar
                  WHERE date LIKE DATE_FORMAT('$row->date', '%Y-%m-%d') ");
                    //date format change back the date format
                    //that fetched earlier
                 foreach ($query2->result() as $r) {
                     $a[$i] = $r->data;     //make data array to put to specific date
                     $i++;                         
                 }
                    $cal_data[substr($row->date,8,2)] = $a;

            }

            return $cal_data;
            } 

  function add_calendar_data($date, $data) {

if ($this->db->select('date')->from('tbl_calendar')
    ->where('date', $date)->count_all_results()) {

  $this->db->where('date', $date)
    ->update('tbl_calendar', array(
    'date' => $date,
    'data' => $data     
  ));

} else {

  $this->db->insert('tbl_calendar', array(
    'date' => $date,
    'data' => $data     
  ));
}

 }
  public function get_todo($year, $month)
  {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(due_date, '%Y-%m-%e') AS date FROM
   tbl_todos WHERE due_date LIKE '$year-$month%' "); //date format eliminates zeros make
          //days look 05 to 5

            $data = array();

            foreach ($query->result() as $row) { //for every date fetch data
                $a = array();
                $i = 0;
                $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT title FROM tbl_todos
                  WHERE due_date LIKE DATE_FORMAT('$row->date', '%Y-%m-%d') ");
                    //date format change back the date format
                    //that fetched earlier
                 foreach ($query2->result() as $r) {
                     $a[$i] = $r->title;     //make data array to put to specific date
                     $i++;                         
                 }
                    $data[substr($row->date,8,2)] = $a;

            }

            return $data;

  }

  function generate ($year, $month) {

    $this->load->library('calendar', $this->conf);
    $cal_data = array();
    $cal_data = $this->get_calendar_data($year, $month);
    $cal_data += $this->get_todo($year, $month);

    return $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $cal_data);

  }

 }
```

Comment: Use [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io) script in your codeigniter...

Comment: plz give me some idea